# C- Mysql - warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

connect to MySQL: works fine.

```
mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, pass, db, 0, NULL, 0);
```

I want to do something like

```
char *status = "";
status = mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, pass, db, 0, NULL, 0);
printf(stauts);
```

the above attempt results in compile error:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Solution is needed.

Comment: Well, basically, read a manual or tutorial about using mysql library in C. At first [mysql_real_connect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-connect.html) one.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-connect.html) `mysql_real_connect` returns a `MYSQL*` connection handler and thus cannot be stored in a `char*`.